# Google Sheets API v4 update cell number format without changing anything else

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-sheets-api

I want to update the number format of cells in Google Sheets API v4 without changing anything else like the background color.

The code below updates the number format of the cell, but also resets things like the background color. I thought setting `$fields = 'userEnteredFormat.numberFormat';`
would leave the other settings alone. Is there a way to get what I want without having to specify all the other formatting settings?

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$auth = __DIR__ . '/path-to-auth.json';
$creds = __DIR__ . '/path-to-creds.json';
$spreadsheetId = 'spreadsheet-id';
$sheetId = 0;
$format = '0.0%';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig($auth);
$token = file_get_contents($creds);
$client->setAccessToken($token);

$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);

$numberFormat = new Google_Service_Sheets_NumberFormat();
$numberFormat->setType('NUMBER');
$numberFormat->setPattern($format);
$cellFormat = new Google_Service_Sheets_CellFormat();
$cellFormat->setNumberFormat($numberFormat);
$cellData = new Google_Service_Sheets_CellData();
$cellData->setUserEnteredFormat($cellFormat);
$rowData = new Google_Service_Sheets_RowData();
$rowData->setValues([$cellData]);
$rows[] = $rowData;

$gridRange = new Google_Service_Sheets_GridRange();
$gridRange->setSheetId($sheetId);
$gridRange->setStartRowIndex(0);
$gridRange->setEndRowIndex(1);
$gridRange->setStartColumnIndex(0);
$gridRange->setEndColumnIndex(1);

$fields = 'userEnteredFormat.numberFormat';

$updateCellsRequest = new Google_Service_Sheets_UpdateCellsRequest();
$updateCellsRequest->setFields($fields);
$updateCellsRequest->setRows($rows);
$updateCellsRequest->setRange($gridRange);

$request = new Google_Service_Sheets_Request();
$request->setUpdateCells($updateCellsRequest);
$batchUpdate = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
$batchUpdate->setRequests([$request]);

$service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($spreadsheetId, $batchUpdate);

?>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with PHP but, you can check [this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/samples/formatting) and [this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/formats#number_format_examples) one about format in Sheets API

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the service when handling that particular request.  It should be fixed sometime next week.  Sorry for the trouble.